# is there a way to fix this error i am getting?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

This is the frontend of my program. This a function to delete a set of records from a table. It gives me this error:project1Database.deleteRec(sd[0])
NameError: name 'sd' is not defined. I know it probably a little mistake by I am still new to coding so anything can help.

```py
def EmployeeRec(event):
    global sd
    searchEmp = employeelist.curselection()[0]
    sd = employeelist.get(searchEmp)
 
    self.txtEmpID.delete(0,END)
    self.txtEmpID.insert(0,sd[1])

    self.txtFirstname.delete(0,END)
    self.txtFirstname.insert(END,sd[2])

    self.txtMiddlename.delete(0,END)
    self.txtMiddlename.insert(END,sd[3])

    self.txtLastname.delete(0,END)
    self.txtLastname.insert(END,sd[4])

    self.txtDob.delete(0,END)
    self.txtDob.insert(END,sd[5])

    self.txtNationality.delete(0,END)
    self.txtNationality.insert(END,sd[6])

    self.txtNI.delete(0,END)
    self.txtNI.insert(END,sd[7])

    self.txtAddres.delete(0,END)
    self.txtAddres.insert(END,sd[8])

    self.txtPostcode.delete(0,END)
    self.txtPostcode.insert(END,sd[9])

    self.txtphonenumber.delete(0,END)
    self.txtphonenumber.insert(END,sd[10])

    self.txtEmail.delete(0,END)
    self.txtEmail.insert(END,sd[11])

    self.txtPassportnumber.delete(0,END)
    self.txtPassportnumber.insert(END,sd[12])

    self.txtPassportexpirydate.delete(0,END)
    self.txtPassportexpirydate.insert(END,sd[13])

    self.txtgender.delete(0,END)
    self.txtgender.insert(END,sd[14])
 

def deleteData():
    if(len(EmpID.get())!=0):
        project1Database.deleteRec(sd[0])
        clearData()
        displayData()
```

This is the backend. This is the table for my program.

```py
import sqlite3

#backend

def employeeData():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('projectv4.db')
    c= conn.cursor()

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(EmployeeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,EmpID text,
    Firstname text,Middlename text, Lastname text,
    Dob text, Nationality text, NI text, Addres text, Postcode text,  phonenumber text,
    Email text, Passportnumber text, Passportexpirydate text,
   gender text)""")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This is the function I am trying to call from my frontend:

```py
def deleteRec(EmployeeID):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('projectv4.db')
    c= conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM employee WHERE EmployeeID = ?", (EmployeeID,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback rather than just the last line, as that contains valuable information about the error

Answer (score 0):

`deleteData` refers to `sd` before initializing it. Assuming you mean the same global variable as in `EmployeeRec`, you need to explicitly state that it's global:

```py
def deleteData():
             
    if(len(EmpID.get())!=0):
        global sd #here!
        project1Database.deleteRec(sd[0])

        clearData()

        displayData()
```